# Prove $\sum a_j b_j \geq (1+\sum_i a_i^2)^{1/2} (1+\sum_i b_j^2)^{1/2}-(\sum a_i^2)^{1/2}(\sum b_j^2)^{1/2}\geq 0$

Tags: inequality

Assume all numbers are real.

I came across this while reading [page 4 of http://home.ku.edu.tr/~amostafazadeh/phys517_518/phys517_2016f/Handouts/A_Jaffi_Lorentz_Group.pdf]; I believe the inequalities presented are of the same form as what is in the title. The second inequality is obvious, but I am having some difficulty proving the first one. Cauchy-Schwartz gives $-(\sum a_i^2)^{1/2}(\sum b_j^2)^{1/2} \leq \sum a_j b_j \leq (\sum a_i^2)^{1/2}(\sum b_j^2)^{1/2}$, but I can't see where to go from there.

I'm sure I'm missing something, because this isn't even true in $1$d for, say, $a=b=1/(2\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: That cannot be correct. If all $b_j$ are zero then the left inequality reduces to $0 \ge (1+\sum_i a_i^2)^{1/2}$, which is obviously wrong. – Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, it seems clearly flawed. I'm afraid I'm missing some very important detail. Fortunately, everything relevant is contained in equation I.6 to I.9 in the link (about half a page).

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. In the document, the greatest value in the equalities is actually $a_0b_0+\sum a_j b_j$, where $|a_0|=(1+\sum a_i^2)^{1/2}$ and $|b_0| = (1+\sum b_j^2)^{1/2}$ (equations I.6 and I.7), instead of just $\sum a_j b_j$; the assumption made in the document before the statement of the inequality was that $a_0$ and $b_0$ have the same sign. I erred in thinking that, since the product in that case is nonnegative, I could simply overestimate the inequality by proving it for $\sum a_j b_j$.

Combining the above with Cauchy-Schwartz (as I mentioned at the end of my question) gives the answer:
$$a_0 b_0 \geq 0 \Rightarrow  a_0b_0+\sum a_j b_j = |a_0||b_0|+\sum a_j b_j = (1+\sum a_i^2)^{1/2} (1+\sum b_j^2)^{1/2}+\sum a_j b_j \overset{\text{C.S.}}{\geq}(1+\sum a_i^2)^{1/2} (1+\sum b_j^2)^{1/2} - (\sum a_i^2)^{1/2}(\sum b_j^2)^{1/2} \geq 0,$$ as required.